# EF's DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity attribute doesn't work for the ulong type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

```
[Table( "User" )]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public ulong Id { get; set; }
    // other columns
}
```

For this code I get the exception:

> System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'User' has no key
>   defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

But changing the Id's type to int, everything works fine.

```
    //...
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
```

How to get the possibility for autocreating tables with an Id having a ulong type capacity ? (using ef's code first obviously)

Comment: Why not just use long/int64. I find i hard to believe you would create more records than it can hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that numeric sql server types are :

> bigint, numeric, bit, smallint, decimal, smallmoney, int, tinyint, money

it becomes clear that CLR type `UInt64` (`ulong`) does not map to any of these types.

Comment: TIL: SQL Server doesn't support unsigned ints. WTF? Only been using it for a couple of years and never had a personal need for an unsigned, so I just *assumed* it could because every. stinking. other. database. in. the. world. can. Oh well.